# Is there a Star Wars adventure for Awesome Adventures?

Tags: game-recommendation, fate, published-adventures

I teach English to a Japanese couple. I discovered they like *Star Wars 4: A New Hope*. I imagine there are a million RPG adventures for it but I want one for the Fate-based *Awesome Adventures* system (as I bought the book in Australia for myself and I don't get reimbursed for expenses).

I want a adventure for two players with pre-generated characters — preferably a man and a woman — any necessary Star Wars setting info, a rather railroady plot so they can just play and get used to the system and the totally new experience of RPG roleplaying, while also learning English. I only have 1½ hours for the lesson but it can obviously be split over several lessons.

Comment: _Awesome Adventurers_ isn't just similar to Fate, it's _built on top of_ the Fate system. It's one of Fate's many concrete adaptions into other systems.

Comment: I realised that after reading its second page- not many references to Fate RPG system.

Comment: I have no experience with it, so I can't make it an answer in good conscience, but I found [Star Wars Fate Edition](http://ryanmdanks.com/?p=11) without any difficulty. It is free, and if you want the Fate Core rules, they are also available both as pay-what-you-want and a [free SRD](fate-srd.com) so there would be no additional expense involved and the Fate concepts you know would carry over.

Comment: I'm not looking for a system but an adventure. If you have one made for Star Wars Fate Edition then I will fiddle it back to Awesome Adventures System.

Comment: I've poked around in all the usual places, but I don't see any Star Wars adventures written for Fate or for Awesome Adventures. Sorry man, might be out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user2617804 Assuming you haven't resolved this need already, I think we could benefit from taking the original request back to basics.

You have two people with an interest in the original *Star Wars* film. You want to play a game in that setting with some pre-generated characters. You have a Fate-powered system that aims for rules lite, gonzo adventure, something action-focussed and pulpy.

I suggest you try [Getting There is Half the Fun](https://boardgamegeek.com/rpgitem/159018/getting-there-half-fun).

It's an adventure written for *Bulldogs!* - but that's a Fate-powered system as well, so you will have fairly immediate compatibility with *Awesome Adventures*.

While the game doesn't come with specific pre-generated characters - it does come with a pile of non-player adversaries. Right at the end of the adventure, if the goal hasn't been achieved an encounter occurs with a pilot and an engineer. Take those characters - Michaeu, the captain of the Dare and its pilot, and Miracle, the ship’s engineer - and make them your player's characters instead.

The adventure actually offers different versions of the all the characters, with different levels of expertise. You could keep it simple and opt for the least experienced version - that way you don't have to explain too much.

Tap into the Mos Eisley section of the Star Wars movie as your source of inspiration. Michaeu and Miracle get themselves a job to deliver a cargo only to discover that someone else has taken the stuff. They need to track down the culprits and get it back - or they'll default on their contract.

The adventure is fairly straightforward. A little investigation, a little fighting. Play up the aliens, the hive of scum and villainy. Throw in some stormtroopers in the background and a long-snouted informer. Seems an ideal fit - even if it isn't specifically *Star Wars* or *Awesome Adventures*.

Comment: Have you played this adventure? Have you played *Bulldogs!* as a drop-in replacement for *Star Wars*?

Comment: I have used this and a couple of the other _Bulldogs!_ adventures - but never used the system itself. In each case, I have used either _Fate Core_ or _Fate Accelerated Edition_. And, in each case, I have taken the core premise and encounters of the adventure, then twisted them to meet the needs of that session - once as a all-goblin treasure hunt, once as a Cthulhu-esque mystery, and once as a Traveller-like scifi (using this adventure).

Comment: Drop the details of your experience into the answer? Experience is an important element of game-rec answers.